# How to crop option set while choosing Image from gallery in Fragment

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have Written code for getting the Image from gallery and cropped and set into the Image View but the image is not set.  If i didnt use crop option coding means its working fine.

I dont know how to use crop option in Fragment.

Here my code:

ProfileFragment:

```js
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
   

    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
   
    private Uri mSelectedImageUri = null;


    Button browseProfilePic;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//For option menu

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_profilepic, container,
                false);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
       
        browseProfilePic = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);

        browseProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
          //Crop option
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX",0);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY",0);
                intent.putExtra("outputX",200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY",150);
                //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.putExtra("return-data",true);
                // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PHOTO);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.d("Request Code:", String.valueOf(requestCode));
        Log.d("Result Code:", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        Log.d("Data:",String.valueOf(data));

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && data != null) {
            mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("Uri:", String.valueOf(mSelectedImageUri));
            //User had pick an image.
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(mSelectedImageUri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //Link to the image
            final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            File file = new File(imageFilePath);
            Log.d("File:", String.valueOf(file));
            if (file != null) {
               Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file));
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);

            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Please anyone help to fix!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: I tried but not working